# Determine elements of set A and the relation R given its quotient set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

I need to find the elements of set $A$, and the relation $R$ given its quotient set $A/R = \{\{c\}, \{a,e\}, \{b,f,g\}\} $

I think I can deduce the elements of $A$ as being $A=\{a,b,c,e,f,g\}$.

However, how can I reconstruct the initial relation? Taking a look at the quotient set, I could deduce that we have three *equivalence classes*. If we take the first one, say $ \{c\}$:

By definition, for an equivalence class, we have that $$[a]_R = \{b | b \in A, a \sim_Rb\}$$

This would mean that one element from set $A$ is only in relation with $c$. My main question is, how can I know **which exact element that is**?

Comment: If $\{c\}$ is an equivalence class then it means that $c$ is equivalent only to itself. By the way, you missed the element $e$ at the beginning.

Comment: To be clear... the set of equivalence classes itself is enough information to define the relation.  $x$ is related to $y$ iff $x$ and $y$ are both members of the same equivalence class.  That said, there doesn't need to be a convenient way to describe the relation without referring to the equivalence classes.

Comment: Sure, we could come up with some contrived example like "*two elements are related if they are both vowels or if they are both c, or are both consonants which are not c*" but that doesn't exactly roll off the tongue here and doesn't make things easier to read.

Comment: @JMoravitz how? Suppose I have A={a,b,c,d}, R={(a,b), (a,c), (b,c), (b,d)}. The equivalence class of [b] = {c, d}, but we don't have a pair (c,d) in the relation R?

Comment: @THE_CRANIUM that choice of $R$ in your comment is not an equivalence relation and as such does not have equivalence classes.

Comment: Your definition of equivalence classes is incomplete.  You are missing the bolded phrase in "**For an equivalence relation $R$** the equivalence class of $a$ denoted $[a]$ is defined as..."  In the event that $R$ is not an equivalence relation then there is no such thing as equivalence classes.  You could still refer to the set you were but it is going to be a different concept entirely and doesn't have to relate to other examples... for example in the language of graph theory calling these either the neighborhood or the outgoing neighborhood of your element.

Comment: An equivalence relation on a set partitions the sets into equivalence classes. Conversely, a partition of a set induces an equivalence relation by defining two elements to be equivalent if they are in the same set of the partition. In your case, the given sets form a partition so we know all of the elements of the set and we know the equivalence relation.